# Space bar shortcut

Tags: shortcut

I can't change space bar shortcut from preferences after I made my own panel, space bar shortcut has disappeared.[image: der] [image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on _"I made my own panel"_

Comment: I mean that I have made my own shortcuts then I saved the changes for ex, I changed rotate instead of middle mouse button to be "Alt + right click mouse button" 

once I saved that changes, space bar shortcut disappeared.